# Check if a field is visible with WTForms (no patches)

Tags: wtforms

What is the cleanest way to confirm if a field is visible with WTForms?

I have a jinja macro which renders form fields, and it simply needs to skip rendering labels for hidden fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did some playing around and reached this conclusion:

```
{% if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %
    {{ field.label }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: FileInput doesn't seem to have this property. I had to do getattr(field.widget, 'input_type', None) != 'hidden'